# Handling array's in post back data - MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm current a WebForms developer that is trying to move to MVC. I'm super excited about MVC and I'm really have fun but I'm running into a weird issue. So what I'm trying to do is create an advanced editor for a "widget". I've posted the code below.

Everything appears to work fine when you add the first 4-5 items but the problem occurs when you delete the 2nd item. Here is a visual example.

First add the 4 values.

[image]

But the problem occurs when we delete the 2nd value. We end up with this...

[image]

What I cannot seem to understand is why does this property act different between the two following lines of code.

```
@Model.Values[i]
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Values[i])
```

My guess is that the @Model and (m =>m) do not reference the same object?

Here is my widget class.

```
public class Widget
{
    #region Constructor

    public Widget()
    {
        ID = 0;
        Name = string.Empty;
        Values = new List<string>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Values")]
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

My controller looks like this.

```
public ViewResult EditWidget(int id)
{
    return View(_widgets.GetWidgetByID(id));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditWidget(Widget widget)
{
    if (!TryUpdateModel(widget))
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Error...";
        return View(widget);
    }

    if (Request.Form["AddWidgetValue"] != null)
    {
        widget.Values.Add(Request.Form["TextBoxWidgetValue"]);
        return View("EditWidget", widget);
    }

    if (Request.Form["DeleteWidgetValue"] != null)
    {
        widget.Values.Remove(Request.Form["ListBoxWidgetValues"]);
        return View("EditWidget", widget);
    }

    _widgets.UpdateWidget(widget);
    _widgets.Save();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And finally my view.

```
@model MvcTestApplication.Models.Widget

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditWidget";
}

<h2>EditWidget</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Widget</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Values.Count; i++)
        {
            @Model.Values[i]
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Values[i])
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Values[i])
            <br />
        }

        @Html.ListBox("ListBoxWidgetValues", new SelectList(Model.Values), new { style = "width: 100%" })<br />
        @Html.TextBox("TextBoxWidgetValue", string.Empty, new { style = "width: 100%" })
        <input type="submit" value="Add" id="AddWidgetValue" name="AddWidgetValue" class="submitButton" />
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" id="DeleteWidgetValue" name="DeleteWidgetValue" class="submitButton" />

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this happening is because HTML helpers first look at ModelState posted values when binding and then in model. This means that if inside your POST controller action you try to modify some value and this same value was part of the initial post request the HTML helper will use the initial value and not the one you modified.

For example in your EditWidget action you are doing this:

```
if (Request.Form["DeleteWidgetValue"] != null)
{
    widget.Values.Remove(Request.Form["ListBoxWidgetValues"]);
    return View("EditWidget", widget);
}
```

You should remove the initially posted value from the model state:

```
if (Request.Form["DeleteWidgetValue"] != null)
{
    var itemToRemove = Request.Form["ListBoxWidgetValues"];
    var index = widget.Values.IndexOf(itemToRemove);
    ModelState.Remove("Values[" + index + "]");
    widget.Values.Remove(itemToRemove);
    return View("EditWidget", widget);
}
```

So the POST request contained:

```
Values[0] = 1
Values[1] = 2
Values[2] = 3
Values[3] = 4
```

Inside the POST action you removed for example the second item so you should also remove it from the model state or the TextBoxFor helper will still use the old one.

You may also find the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) useful. It's for ASP.NET MVC 2 WebForms but it would be trivial to adapt it to Razor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will test it. Am I doing this correctly? Is there a better way of handling a list of strings in a listbox?

Comment: @Bobby Cannon, look at the blog post I have linked to: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ It illustrates another approach using AJAX.

Comment: I guess whats throwing me off is that I expected "return View("EditWidget", widget")" to update / replace the model state. I guess that is not happening?

Comment: @Bobby Cannon, `return View("EditWidget", widget)` passes the updated model to the view, but inside the view you use the TextBoxFor helper which uses the POSTed values, not the one from the model which is passed to this view and which you updated in your action.

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov, So @Model is the updated model but (m => m) references the posted values? So is there a way to do @Html.TextBoxFor against the @Model object?

Comment: @Bobby Cannon, no there isn't. That's by design and that's the expected behavior of all HTML helpers. You will have to write your own html helper if you want to modify this behavior but I wouldn't recommend you so. Did you checkout the article I have linked to?

Comment: @ Daren Dimitrov, I'm checking our your link and I'm liking it. I think this is a better solution. BTW, the solution above did not work.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1071/discussion-between-bobby-cannon-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: I still cannot accept this answer because it didn't work. I would like for you to remove this post and post the link to the ajax approach so I can accept the answer.

Comment: @Bobby Cannon, are you talking about the Steve Sanderson blog post? It's already part of my answer. The last sentence. You want me to remove the previous part of my answer?

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov, Yes. The previous part of the answer did not work. Maybe I'm missing something but I feel hesitant to mark it as an answer because it did not work for me.

Comment: @Bobby Cannon, in this case you could update your question and say which part of my answer worked for you. Because when I tested it worked for me.